# where to find where the value for the diplay block is coming from

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How do I find where the value for a display item in coming from in Oracle forms? The property pallete shows the database item is null, as it's a display item. I need to know which column/table populates the value. I am a beginner in forms any help would be highly appreciated

Opened property pallete, checked that

Comment: If that display item's name is identical to a column's name(eg. not null) of a data source(table,view..etc.) which stays in "Query Data Source Name" of "Database" node within the Property Palette of the block that contains the display item, then should populate the value.

Answer (score 0):

In Forms, everything is set via PL/SQL units so - if you want to find *something*, search! Here's how:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, worked for me. Also are there any helpful resources to study about Oracle forms or packages

Comment: As of "packages", they are part of PL/SQL documentation. This (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/index.htm) is Oracle 10g (really old, but contains nice "Most popular" section) - have a look at "PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference" and "Application Developer's Guide - Fundamentals" (see if you can find similar documentation for Oracle database version you use). As of "Oracle Forms", I took a course; which Forms version do you use?